# Change the default "Outlook Template" location

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I try to save an outlook file as an "Outlook Template", upon switching the file type to outlook template the folder switches to something like:

user/applicationdata/microsoft/templates

I want to change this to another folder on a shared drive. How can I do this?

Im on both xp and windows 7 using outlook 2007 and 2010.

Answer (score 3):

In order to modify the path for user defined templates you will need to go into Microsoft Word (I know the option dose not exist in Outlook, but will work for both).

*File > Options > Advanced > General > File Locations...*

In the pop-up window select the **User templates** File type and change the default location. It will be modified for all Office products you have installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's no option within Outlook itself to change the default location but you can change this via the `UserTemplates` Registry value name.

The `UserTemplates` value doesn’t exist by default so it has to be created manually in the Registry.

Key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Common\General`

Value name: `UserTemplates`

Value type: `REG_SZ (string value)`

For the value enter the path where you want your templates to be stored to and opened from by default. You don’t have to enclose the path in quotes and the path may contain spaces.

Examples:

- To a different location on on a local disk: `D:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\Templates`
- To a network share: `\\SERVER01\Office Shared\Templates`